# replace an angular spa by another angular spa

Tags: angular

I want to split my app into 3 different ones.

- /home will be its own Angular App `HomeApp`
- /details will be its own Angular App `DetailsApp`
- /cart will be its own Angular App `CartApp`

I want to develop and deploy them independently.
Is it possible to create an HTML page which loads the corresponding Angular App based on the route?
e.g.

`/home` --> HomeApp will be loaded

if i navigate to `/details` then `HomeApp` will be removed from the DOM and `DetailApp` gets loaded.

Note: 2 angular applications do not coexsist at the same time. To me it would be sufficient to have 1 app in the dom at a time

Comment: Why you need three different apps why not three different components within single app to me these three Home, Details, Cart looks like different route of single application.

Comment: I really want the applciations to be developed independently and also deployed independently

Comment: Ant specific purpose you need three different app for three URLs. This can achieve as @KamranKhatti said.

Comment: @matthias angular generates one index.html files which on client side responsible to display all other page. Here three app which will have three index.html that cannot be deploy on the the same page. you can create folders on the /var/www/html/ and deploy three application over there.

Comment: i don't know if this will work as you expect.maybe try using  `<iframe>` in a single html page.

Answer (score 0):

Home, details, and carts are features of the same app. And as we already know we cannot deploy multiple apps on same domain. Switching angular app is still not a good choice even if it would be possible. If these 3 feature module would have been completely separate from each other , than we would have to deploy them on different domains (think google docs, sheets, drive etc)

As they are feature module , develop them as **completely separate lazy loaded feature module** . This way you can give these module to different teams to work on. For deployment , a basic CI continuous integration and proper version control would be enough.